# SharePoint Designer 2013 - 2010 Workflow Copy List Item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am attempting to create/use the variable for the 2010 Workflow function "Copy List Item". Using "Create List Item" will give a variable, but the "Copy List Item" does not.

Basically, I want to email the user the link for the newly created item. Perhaps if I create item in list (outputs to variable) I can then copy all fields into the variable for 'current item' but I'm not seeing this as available.

Comment: If you use Copy List Item option, you'll have to lookup the list item id after that action since it doesn't return an item id for you.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's how I would do it..

1. Do the create item action, it outputs to the variable
2. That variable (called create by default) is the ID of the List Item you just created. You can then create a link to that list item to be included in the e-mail:

[image]

So construct your URL like this:

[image]

That's assuming you want to have them see the "Read" view of the form, you could always point them at the Edit form. (Replace YourList with the name of your list)

That should honestly do it..